# How to add Rupee Symbol to table td dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am receiving the following response from back end

```
var jsondata = [{
    "vendor_name": "Apple",
    "discount": "2 Rs"
}, {
    "vendor_name": "Banana",
    "discount": "10 % "
}];
```

The discount can be in Rs or in percent .

My requirement is that if discount is of Rs then i need to add the Rupee symbol instead of the text (Rs)

The below is the Rupee symbol

```
<span class='WebRupee'>&#x20B9;</span>
```

This is my program i couldn't able to display Rupee symbol

```
var jsondata = [{
    "vendor_name": "Apple",
    "discount": "2 Rs"
}, {
    "vendor_name": "Banana",
    "discount": "10 % "
}];

var orderdetailshtml = '';
for(var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
    var name = jsondata[i].vendor_name;
    var discount = jsondata[i].discount;
    var appendtovalue = '';

    if(discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
        appendtovalue = ""
    } else if(discount.indexOf("Rs") > -1) {
        appendtovalue = ""
    }

    orderdetailshtml += '<tr>\
        <td>' + i + '</td>\
        <td>' + name + '</td>\
        <td>' + discount + ' ' + appendtovalue + '</td>\
        </tr>';
}
$("#orderstable tbody").html(orderdetailshtml);
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/rav3333m/3/

Comment: Use regex to replace string by it's symbol [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z21czmtt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would to be do a string replace on discount if `indexOf("Rs")` is greater than `-1`.

```
discount = discount.replace('Rs', '<span class="WebRupee">&#x20B9;</span>');
```

Here's the updated javascript

```
var jsondata = [{
    "vendor_name": "Apple",
    "discount": "2 Rs"
}, {
    "vendor_name": "Banana",
    "discount": "10 % "
}];

var orderdetailshtml = '';
for(var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
    var name = jsondata[i].vendor_name;
    var discount = jsondata[i].discount;
    var appendtovalue = '';

    if(discount.indexOf("%") > -1) {
        appendtovalue = ""
    } else if(discount.indexOf("Rs") > -1) {
        discount = discount.replace('Rs', '<span class="WebRupee">&#x20B9;</span>');
        appendtovalue = ""
    }

    orderdetailshtml += '<tr>\
        <td>' + i + '</td>\
        <td>' + name + '</td>\
        <td>' + discount + ' ' + appendtovalue + '</td>\
        </tr>';
}
$("#orderstable tbody").html(orderdetailshtml);
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0y70sht/) I created.

Answer (score 1):

Since your string is forming part of a HTML string any way, the simplest way would be to replace instances of "Rs" with the code:

```
if(discount.indexOf("Rs") > -1) {
        appendtovalue = "";      
        discount = discount.replace('Rs', '<span class="WebRupee">&#x20B9;</span>');
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sysnull/b6ujjnc6/1/